# Need to show keyboard after image upload in the android-app

Tags: bug, android-app, images

After image uploading text stub for image description is selected, but there is no keyboard on screen:

> [image: nokey]

If I tap on the text to enable keyboard, selection will dissapear.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1626721325f7f)